# Unable To Connect Laravel to MailChimp (laravel 5.4)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, mailchimp

I have to define List ID and MailChimp API Key in my `.env` file. I'm sure both are fine even I am not getting any error but email in not inserting in my List I installed https://github.com/spatie/laravel-newsletter (**spatie/laravel-newsletter**)  Package.

Here is my method

```
public function subscribe(Request $request)
{
    $email = request('email');
    Newsletter::subscribe($email);

    Session::flash('subscribed', 'Successfully subscribed.');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Then I check subscribe Method in `Newsletter.php`

it is as

```
public function subscribe($email, $mergeFields = [], $listName = '', $options = [])
{

    $list = $this->lists->findByName($listName);

    $options = $this->getSubscriptionOptions($email, $mergeFields, $options);

    $response = $this->mailChimp->post("lists/{$list->getId()}/members", $options);
    if (! $this->lastActionSucceeded()) {
        return false;
    }

    return $response;
}
```

I print options variable it returns output as

```
array:3 [▼
    "email_address" => "bluemoon@gmail.com"
    "status" => "subscribed"
    "email_type" => "html"
]
```

Then I print below variable **$response it returns false** Please Help whats wrong with this.

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will directly resolve your issue, but you need to run the following command in your terminal:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\Newsletter\NewsletterServiceProvider"
```

This creates a `laravel-newsletter.php` in the `config` directory, that's where your List ID and MailChimp API key should go.

PS: the package seems to have an issue with `env` so don't use it, just enter your keys as strings.