# Getting "Mailchimp_Error you must provide MailChimp API key in laravel 5.4 project

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am following this tutorial [integrate mailchimp api with laravel 5](http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-mailchimp-api-integration-from-scratch-with-exampleexample.html)on integrating mailchimp API with a laravel 5.4 project.  It is saying that I should put my APIKEY in the .env file like so.

```
MAILCHIMP_API_KEY="API 1234567891011121314"
```

I have two questions
1) Is this correct to put it in the .env file.
2) Is the format in the .env correct.

Thanks for your help into looking into this for me.

Comment: Looking at the comments on that link, try `MAILCHIMP_APIKEY`.

Comment: Thanks, Jon.  I am not getting the error now.  The problem is I am getting any thing come through to MailChimp or a success message.  Might have to post another question.

Comment: Maybe this post will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44911181/unable-to-connect-laravel-to-mailchimp-laravel-5-4

Comment: That would mean having to install a new package and starting again.