# Getting an error when starting php artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am getting the following error when starting my laravel server.

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]   
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ']'
```

I am trying to create a web app that integrates with the mailchimp api.  I am using the following package. [Manage Newsletters.](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-newsletter)

Now I have created and the `laravel-newsletter.php` and inserted the api key and list id as per the following post [connecting laravel to mailchimp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44911181/unable-to-connect-laravel-to-mailchimp-laravel-5-4)

Below is how I have listed the api key and list id.

```
<?php

return [

    /*
     * The api key of a MailChimp account. You can find yours here:
     * https://us10.admin.mailchimp.com/account/api-key-popup/
     */
    // 'apiKey' => env('MAILCHIMP_APIKEY'),
    'MAILCHIMP_APIKEY'='API 1234567891011121314',

    /*
     * When not specifying a listname in the various methods, use the list with this name
     */
    'defaultListName' => 'subscribers',

    /*
     * Here you can define properties of the lists you want to
     * send campaigns.
     */
    'lists' => [

        /*
         * This key is used to identify this list. It can be used
         * in the various methods provided by this package.
         *
         * You can set it to any string you want and you can add
         * as many lists as you want.
         */
        'subscribers' => [

            /*
             * A mail chimp list id. Check the mailchimp docs if you don't know
             * how to get this value:
             * http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/managing-subscribers/find-your-list-id
             */
            // 'id' => env('MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID'),
            'id'='123456789',
        ],
    ],

    /*
     * If you're having trouble with https connections, set this to false.
     */
    'ssl' => true,
  ];
```

Comment: `'MAILCHIMP_APIKEY'='API 1234567891011121314',` missing a `>`. Same with `'id'='123456789',`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just a typo, on

```
'MAILCHIMP_APIKEY'='API 1234567891011121314',
```

should be

```
'MAILCHIMP_APIKEY'=>'API 1234567891011121314',
```

and on `'id'=>'123456789',`

Comment: Is that the same for the list id?

Comment: @AltBrian _All_ key/value pair in an array must be: `"key" => "value",`

Comment: @AltBrian, you can accept as answer if this resolves your issue

Comment: It wouldn't let me a few minutes ago.  Have done now.

Comment: I am now getting `(1/1) Exception
Invalid MailChimp API key `` supplied.`

Comment: As error message says,  key is not valid. If you are sure key is correct then cross check name of key that you have changed. Not sure about key name until I know where and how it used